# Table doesn't immediately show data obtained through ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting json data from an ajax call as shown below:

```
/*
 * Get list of vendors and populate table
 */
function getVendors() {

    $
            .ajax({
                async : true,
                type : "GET",
                url : "/JavaTestService/rs/TestService/getMVendors?version=2",
                dataType : "json",

                success : function(json) {
                    //add element to vendors array
                    $.each(json.resultSet.merchandiseVendor, function(index,item){
                        nameLocal = item.name;
                        numberLocal = item.number;

                        vendorData[vendorDataCounter] = {
                                name : nameLocal,
                                number : numberLocal
                        }
                        vendorDataCounter++;
                    });
                    initVendorTable();
                },

                error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });

}
```

The initVendorTable() method is meant to populate a table with the data obtained from the above ajax call. initVendorTable() method shown below:

```
/*
 * Initialize the table containing the list of vendors
 */
function initVendorTable() {

    jQuery("#supplierTable").jqGrid({
        datatype : "local",
        height : 250,
        colNames : [ 'Vendor Number', 'Vendor Name' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'number',
            index : 'name',
            width : 200,
            sorttype : "int"
        }, {
            name : 'name',
            index : 'number',
            width : 200
        } ],
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        sortname : 'number',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        caption : "Suppliers"
    });
    for(var i=0;i<=vendorData.length;i++){
        $("#supplierTable").jqGrid("addRowData",i+1,vendorData[i]);
    }

    alert(vendorData);

}
```

I call the getVendors() method from a button click:

```
$(function() {

    $("#supplierSearchArea").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        height : 400,
        width : 'auto',
        modal : true,
        title : 'Browse Suppliers'
    });

    $("#supplierPopupButton").click(function(e) {

        $("#supplierSearchArea").dialog("open");
        getVendors();

    });

});
```

The problem is that when I first click the button and the popup containing the table appears, the table is empty. This is because the array which I use to populate the table is empty.

After stepping through the code, I've found that the initVendorTable() method gets called before the getVendors() method, even though I call the getVendors() method before the initVendorTable() method in the code. Is this an ajax quirk? Any suggestions on how I should work around this?

Comment: I guess is because of asynchrounus nature of AJAX call

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I changed async to false which generally solves the problem, but now the popup takes a pretty long time to load. Should I just throw up a loading gif?

Comment: I suggest to avoid using of sync call. Use promise or .done() instead

Comment: You guys, he is using callbacks. jQuery.ajax's "success" option defines a callback on the successful completion of the ajax request. The real problem is global variable leaks and parameter passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the vendorData array to your initVendorTable function. You'll have to edit the function definition for it to receive this data as a parameter. Also, from the looks of it, you're leaking globals, which is giving you unexpected results. Use the `var` keyword whenever you define variables to prevent this.

This is my best attempt at a fix:

```
function getVendors() {

    $.ajax({
                async : true,
                type : "GET",
                url : "/JavaTestService/rs/TestService/getMVendors?version=2",
                dataType : "json",

                success : function(json) {

                    // initialize vendorData to empty array
                    // var keeps this variable local
                    var vendorData = [];

                    $.each(json.resultSet.merchandiseVendor, function(index, item){

                        // add element to vendorData
                        vendorData.push({
                                "name": item.name,
                                "number": item.number
                        });
                    });

                    // send the constructed array to the initVendorTable function
                    initVendorTable(vendorData);
                },

                error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
    });

}
```

And here's the new definition for the initVendorTable function:

```
/*
 * Initialize the table containing the list of vendors
 * vendorData is the array of data to process
 */

function initVendorTable(vendorData) {

    jQuery("#supplierTable").jqGrid({
        datatype : "local",
        height : 250,
        colNames : [ 'Vendor Number', 'Vendor Name' ],
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'number',
            index : 'name',
            width : 200,
            sorttype : "int"
        }, {
            name : 'name',
            index : 'number',
            width : 200
        } ],
        rowNum : 10,
        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
        sortname : 'number',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        caption : "Suppliers"
    });
    for(var i=0;i<=vendorData.length;i++){
        $("#supplierTable").jqGrid("addRowData",i+1,vendorData[i]);
    }

    alert(vendorData);

}
```

I'm assuming your usage of the jqGrid plugin is accurate, because I'm not familiar with how it works.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using `async:false` one solution can be a `call` like this :

```
$.ajax({
//your ajax call
  ..
}).done(function(data){ //pass data to done callback
//use data
});
```

maybe you can set some loading gif as you said.

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/